# ip instead localhost - use paypal sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ip, localhost, paypal-sandbox

i want to test paypal transaction in my website.

problem is that they want to work with IP instead localhost of my machine.

how can i change localhost into some static IP address?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you give an example of what “they want” and how would you want to use it?

Comment: You probably need to expose your website, for example using www.no-ip.com so the paypal gateway can contact it from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ip of localhost is 127.0.0.1 , use it

**EDIT**

By the way you can call in cmd ipconfig -all and look at your ip

plus you can check it here [My IP](http://whoer.net/)

Comment: If PayPal uses that IP when communicating with the website, then that won't work.

Comment: If website doesn't stand on local computer

Comment: No, even if it did. From the point of view of PayPal, the IP address of your computer is not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: He test his own paypal transaction, so he can use 127.0.0.1

Comment: i can put ip from  ipconfig instead localhost and call the page?? really? hehe

Comment: Oh yes, i get dedicated Internet line, so for me this function work ))